# assets folder (Xaringan) gets overwhelmed with new folders

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, xaringan

as of recently I am noticing that the assets folder of my Xaringan presentations fill up with loads of weird folders, after knitting. I have several useful subfolders (e.g., css, images, js), but there are easily 200 folders created after knitting. All of then have random names like "00e3144c-c556-4b66-b50a-c44d64246b85-9.9.9" (the "-.9.9.9" seems the only non-random repetitive part of the folder names).

Where do these folders come from/what causes their appearance? And: are they strictly necessary or can I prevent them from being created? They are empty, but totally flock the assets folder.

Comment: You need to provide a reproducible example. Without that, my guess is that you used a certain R package that generates an HTML dependency with a random name.

Comment: My slideset is very big and contains some proprietary material, so I am not sure how to turn this into a reprex. That said, I am wondering what (or even: why) packages would create randomly names HTML dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same overwhelming empty directory problem.

Yihui gave a possible cause - HTML dependency. I went down that route and discovered it was `xaringanExtra` which uses `htmltools` that would lead to empty directories - `xaringan` alone wouldn't.

It seems Garrick (author of `xaringanExtra`) has been aware of such issue, hence [this PR](https://github.com/rstudio/htmltools/pull/276). I'd wait for it to be merged then try again. Hope this is helpful.